# XMLHttpRequest response form with submit that does not work

Tags: html, forms, xmlhttprequest

I've got a problem with XMLHttpRequest. I have a  that has a onChange event that calls a function which makes an XMLHttpRequest to get the response from a PHP page. Here's a sample of the code the PHP sends back:

```
<form method="post" action="page_to_load.php">
<input class='button' type='submit' name='cancel' value='Annuler' />
<input class='button' type='submit' name='save' value='Enregistrer' />
</form>
```

When I click either one of the buttons, nothing happens. Is there a special way to deal with a XMLHttpRequest that sends back a form?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: whats ure onChange callback function? and u might wnat to post the code for the XMLHttpRequest if it's not part of the onChange callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In fact I had to use Javascript to submit my form.